# Add x <= y == z as constraint in Gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to do something like:

`model.addConstr( (x <= y) == z )` where `z` is a binary constraint. In other words: `z` should be 1 if `x` is smaller than `y`, otherwise 0.

Gurobi crashes with:

`model.addConstr(z == (x <= y))
  File "model.pxi", line 2966, in gurobipy.Model.addConstr (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:88191)
  File "linexpr.pxi", line 461, in gurobipy.LinExpr.__sub__ (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:34910)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'TempConstr'`

Comment: `True` and `False` have numeric values `1` and `0`, respectively.  `model.addConstr(x <= y)` should work.  If you want to be a little more obvious about what you're doing you can use `model.addConstr( 1 if x <= y else 0)`

Comment: Is this also possible if x and y are gurobi vars?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it in case x and y are fully continuous GurobiVar instances. The [Big M method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method#Other_usage) is a well established way of solving these kind of problems.

A simple example:

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB

m = Model()
x = m.addVar(lb=-GRB.INFINITY)
y = m.addVar(lb=-GRB.INFINITY)
z = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY)

# To be numerically stable, the big M has to be
# a similar order of magnitude as the absolute value
# of the difference between x and y
BIG_M = 10000

# Force z to become 1 if y is larger than x
m.addConstr(BIG_M * z >= y - x)

# Force z to be zero if y is smaller than x
m.addConstr(BIG_M * (1 - z) >= x - y)
```